# How to setup a many to many form in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have three entities, ChannelEntity -> MatchChannelEntity <- MatchEntity, the MatchChannelEntity saves the many to many relations between the other two tables, I want a form to list all the channels using checkboxes, and if a match has one the of channels, the checkbox of that channel is selected, how can I do this ?

Here is the Form type code:

```
class MatchhType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('channels', 'entity', array('label' => 'Channels', 
                                          'class'         => 'Mikay\MikiBundle\Entity\Channel',
                                          'multiple'      => true,
                                          'expanded'      => true,
                                          'query_builder' => function ($repository) 
                                          { 
                                            return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC'); 
                                          },))
```

The MatchChannel type:

```
class MatchChannel
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $match_id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Matchh", inversedBy="channels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="match_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable="true")
     */
     private $match;

    /**
     * @var integer $channel_id
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Channel", inversedBy="mathces")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="channel_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable="true")
     */
   private $channel;
```

I will use an example to explain, say, I have three channels: channel A, channel B and channel C, and one match: match M, the match M has one channel A, this relation is saved in the match_channel table, I want a match form to show all the channels, and channel A is checked because it is owned by match M, others stay unchecked

Comment: You need the entity field type: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: I'm using the entity field type, but my situation is far more complex, what I want is list all the channels from the channel table, and check the ones(saved in the match_channel table) the match owns.

Comment: You can retrieve the channels from the channel table within your field type definition, check my link. Anyway, you definitely need to show some code and explain your problem in details if you want a detailed answer.

Comment: Yes, I did have loaded the channels from the channel table successfully. I will use an example to explain, say, I have three channels: channel A, channel B and channel C, and one match: match M, the match M has one channel A, this relation is saved in the match_channel table, I want a match form to show all the channels, and channel A is checked because it is owned by match M, others stay unchecked.

Comment: You would better put these explanations in your question, not in the comment (and try to make it clearer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I will close this question. That's because I set up the many to many relation between the two tables wrong, and the correct way is as following(I trimed the code a bit):

Many to many: One match has many channels and one channel has many matches.

Match:

```
class Match
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Channel", inversedBy="matches")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="match_channels")
     */
    private $channels;
```

Channel:

```
class Channel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Match", mappedBy="channels")
     */
    private $matches;
```

Doctrine will automatically create the cross reference table for you, named MatchChannels.
Note the **JoinTable** annonation, it is very important.

And when you done, you can create a many to many form easily, just like you create other type of forms/fields.

Comment: I have finally found a workaround for this. You may look into the source code http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/07/symfnoy2-many-to-many-relation-with.html