# How make a form for many to many relations with additional columns in symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have Classes like below :

```
Class Order
{
   // Order have many Product
   // One to Many ->  ProductOrder
}

Class ProductOrder
{
    $order
    $product
    $type
    // other variable  
}

Class Product
{
   // Product has many Order
   // One to Many ->  ProductOrder
}
```

Basically I have `@manytomany` with additional columns, so I need to have `ProductOrder` in middle based on the note in yellow box [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional).

My question is how I can have one form with `One Order` and `Multiple Products`.

Something like [How to setup a many to many form in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553636/how-to-setup-a-many-to-many-form-in-symfony2) but I need the middle `UserTask` class. If I use Many-to-many with no middle class I can create form easily and everything works fine, but having the middle class and the same functionality is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use form collections.

My question & answer regarding form collections:
[Form Collection Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234149/form-collection-error)

Form Collections from Symfony 2 docs:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Symfony 2.0: Embedded Forms for Collections:
http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=90

Comment: I have used form collections for other purposes, my point here is how I can skip the middle class in form collection. You have `User` form which can have a collection of `UserTask` not `Task`.